# How to play animation when after scroll point is reached?

Tags: javascript, css, html, animation

I just saw http://www.archer-group.com/approach

and this made me wanna make my portfolio animation like that.
The animation plays when user scroll it to the specified scroll area/section.
When you scroll down to step 3,step 4, and step 5, the animation plays and resets again when scrolled up or down from the scroll view section.

I saw the flickr.com website and the animation looks different cuz they're playing a video instead of a graphic animation(maybe css) like archer-group.com.

So i have this code below that im trying to delay animation until i scroll the page to that animation section. Can anyone show a simple code to do it. Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
div {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background: red;
-webkit-animation: myfirst 5s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
animation: myfirst 5s;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes myfirst {
0%   {background: red;}
25%  {background: yellow;}
50%  {background: blue;}
100% {background: green;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes myfirst {
0%   {background: red;}
25%  {background: yellow;}
50%  {background: blue;}
100% {background: green;}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<br>
<br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>   <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>  <br><br><br><br>

<p><b>Note:</b> This example </p>
<p><b>Note:</b> This is a sample text.</p>

<div></div>

</body>
/html>
```

Comment: There are many SO questions on the subject. You need to use javascript and the page's scroll event. Try [googling](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8&q=animation%20scroll%20page) before asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically this can be achieved my keeping track of `scrollTop`, and then using `if` statements in the callback function to play an animation/make element visible.

For example:

```
$(function () {

    var $window = $(window);

    $window.scroll(function (event) {
        var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();

        if (scrollTop < 400)
           console.log("hi");
    });
});
```

Comment: @ZachSaucier why is that?

Comment: Because the content will not always be 400 pixels down the page from the start